# How do I add a custom body class to the admin area of a page?

Tags: posts, admin

I tried with this code in `functions.php`of my website's child theme.

```
add_filter('admin_body_class', 'custom_body_class');
function custom_body_class($classes) {
    if (is_page(8))
        $classes[] = 'home-admin-area';
    return $classes;
}
```

But the class "home-admin-area" is not added. Is there any error in this code?

Edit 1: I used `is_page()` function for backend page which was wrong. I tried with this also but it somehow did not work.

```
add_filter('admin_body_class', 'custom_body_class');
function custom_body_class($classes) {
    if ($_GET['post']==8)
        $classes[] .= ' new-class ';
    return $classes;
}
```

Comment: Please refer this at once **https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_body_class/** and review your code

Comment: Already checked this page @PratikPatel and I have tried adding space before and after the class but it didn't help.

Comment: is_page is a front end function, what are you trying to test for on an admin screen? That you’re *editing* page with id of 8?

Comment: It's not *just* a space that you need to add - it has to be handled as a string, not an array (see answer below).

Comment: You're right and I am sorry @Milo I didn't pay attention to this. I wanted to add a class to my home page admin area only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `admin_body_class` both with global post_id and `get_current_screen` function:

```
add_filter('admin_body_class', 'wpse_320244_admin_body_class');

function wpse_320244_admin_body_class($classes) {
    global $post;

    // get_current_screen() returns object with current admin screen
    // @link https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_current_screen
    $current_screen = get_current_screen();

    if($current_screen->base === "post" && absint($post->ID) === 8) {
        $classes .= ' home-admin-area';
    }

    return $classes;
}
```

You can also use $pagenow variable. It seems that this way would be preferable, because `get_current_screen()` maybe undefined in some cases:

```
add_filter('admin_body_class', 'wpse_320244_admin_body_class');

function wpse_320244_admin_body_class($classes) {
    global $post, $pagenow;

    // $pagenow contains current admin-side php-file
    // absint converts type to int, so we can use strict comparison
    if($pagenow === 'post.php' && absint($post->ID) === 8) {
        $classes .= ' home-admin-area';
    }

    return $classes;
}
```

Comment: It worked and helped me achieve what I wanted but could you please explain it a little?

Comment: I added some explanation

Answer (score 1):

`admin_body_class` passes its values as a string, not an array.  (This differs from `body_class` which *does* pass an array.  (See [the documentation for `admin_body_class`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_body_class/))

So what you need is:

```
add_filter('admin_body_class', 'custom_body_class');
function custom_body_class($classes) {
    if (is_page(8))
        $classes .= ' home-admin-area';
    return $classes;
}
```

Note how it's adding as a string with a leading space.

However, not sure if this will work because I am wondering if you're using the correct filter for what you want to do.  Your use of `is_page()` makes me wonder - is this something you're doing in the admin? Or is this a front end thing?

Comment: Yes I made a mistake. I wanted to add a class to the admin area of my home page for which I cannot use is_page as pointed out by milo in comments.

Comment: could you please help me out with this?

Comment: I don't know if I can. I'm still not clear on what you're actually trying to do with it. So my suggestion would be trying it without the "if" check first. That way you'll know if you're even close. If that doesn't work at all, then admin_body_class is not the right filter for what you're trying to do.